# i can't get this query right

Tags: sql

i got a two table the 1st one looks like this

```
Leave       Limit
-----------------
vacation      15
sick          10
absent         9
```

and the second one..

```
Person             Leave      Use
-------------------------------
Chuck Norris     sick        1
Bruce Lee        absent      2
```

what i want it to do is to join the tables and when i select a person it will display like this

```
ex. i select Chuck Norris 

Leave        Limit        Use
------------------------------
vacation       15          0
sick           10          1
absent          9          0
```

Here's what i've done already....

```
SELECT        LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Limit, ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.Use), 0) AS Expr1, 
              LeavetypTbl.Limit- ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.USE), 0) AS DayLeft
FROM          LeavetypTbl LEFT OUTER JOIN
              LeaveTbl ON LeavetypTbl.Leave = LeaveTbl.Leave
WHERE         LeaveTbl.Person ='Chuck Norris'
GROUP BY LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Limit
```

but the result is not what i expect it..lol

```
Leave    Limit    Use    DayLeft
```

---

```
Sick       10       1          9
```

i only get 1 row will..

Comment: You only get one row, because only one row exists for Chuck Norris in your second table.

Comment: His data is corrupt and hence entire question is invalid: Chuck Norris is never sick ;)

Comment: lol........................

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get only one row because you are limiting the results to only `'Chuck Norris'` in the top-level `WHERE` clause. However, `Chuck Norris` never took vacations or absences, so the other two rows from the outer join got eliminated by the `WHERE` clause. Move it to the `ON` clause to get the results that you expect:

```
SELECT        LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Limit, ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.Use), 0) AS Expr1, 
              LeavetypTbl.Limit- ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.USE), 0) AS DayLeft
FROM          LeavetypTbl LEFT OUTER JOIN
              LeaveTbl ON LeavetypTbl.Leave = LeaveTbl.Leave AND LeaveTbl.Person ='Chuck Norris'
GROUP BY LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Limit
```

Answer (score 3):

add person filter in JOIN condition like this:

```
SELECT        LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Limit, ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.Use), 0) AS Expr1, 
              LeavetypTbl.Limit- ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.USE), 0) AS DayLeft
FROM          LeavetypTbl LEFT OUTER JOIN
              LeaveTbl ON LeavetypTbl.Leave = LeaveTbl.Leave
                          and LeaveTbl.Person ='Chuck Norris'
GROUP BY LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Limit
```